# Ruby Datamapper model wrapped around a module prefix module name in the table name in sql query

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have a datamapper model as:

```
module abc
    class Post
         include DataMapper::Resource
         property :title, String
         property :body,  Text
    end
end
```

Note, my class is wrapped around module abc

### In other file

I have:

```
abc::Post.all
```

This should make call to query:

```
select * from posts
```

But it calls

```
select * from abc_posts
```

Table name get a prefix added `abc_` . How can I remove it. I don't keep model around the module, then it works as expected. But my codebase needs model to be inside the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution at http://rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/master/DataMapper/NamingConventions/Resource/UnderscoredAndPluralizedWithoutModule

```
repository(:myreponame).adapter.resource_naming_convention = DataMapper::NamingConventions::Resource::UnderscoredAndPluralizedWithoutModule
```

change :myreponame

Also at http://datamapper.rubyforge.org/dm-core/DataMapper/NamingConventions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your storage name(s) explicitly:

http://datamapper.org/docs/legacy.html